# Wordpress upload file size

Tags: php, wordpress, google-compute-engine

I'm a noob and using Wordpress on Google cloud.  When attempting to upload a new theme, I get the following error message:

> The uploaded file exceeds the `upload_max_filesize` directive in `php.ini`.

This is a limitation seems to be set by Google Compute Engine.  I've found info about the limitation being set in the `php.ini` file, but I can't seem to locate that file anywhere.

Can anyone give some idiot proof, step-by-step instructions to increase the upload size beyond 2MB?  I've installed the WP plug-ins that should do this, but the problem must be server side.

Comment: @HelpingHands This question has nothing to do with wordpress.

Comment: Has nothing to do with Wordpress, it's a php setting.  Generally php.ini is located  in /etc/php5/      Does OP have shell access to go edit php.ini?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: Do you have ftp/ssh access to your cloud directory?

Comment: @Ronald - Did you try this code in wp-config .php?          define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

Comment: @HelpingHands please realize you can not overwrite `php.ini` setting by _any WP setting_.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what operating system you are using or what version of PHP you are using.  I run an Ubuntu 12.04 instance from Amazon Web Services using PHP-FPM.  But, the instructions should be *basically* the same for you.  The directory where your php.ini file is saved may be slightly different in item 3.  Go hunt for it.

1. Log in to your server via SSH.
2. Change user to root:  `sudo /bin/bash`
3. Edit the php.ini file:  `nano /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`
4. Find the line that says `upload_max_filesize = 2M` .  In nano, you can search by typing Ctrl W.
5. Change to whatever file size you want Whatever you type must have an M (megabytes) or G (gigabytes) at the end (e.g. `upload_max_filesize = 200M` or `=1G`).

Aim for the lowest number that you NEED, and keep in mind that PHP has another setting elsewhere that sets how long it will wait before a timeout.  You can set a 2G upload limit, but if your timeout is 30 seconds you're still going to fail unless you can upload 2G in 30 seconds. As a general rule, aim low.

6. Type Ctrl X to exit, save your file changes.
7. Restart PHP by typing `service php5-fpm restart`

Comment: Read carefully please. It's using Google Cloud services. To install Wordpress... i gues it's using AppEngine not a VPS or normal Machine.

Comment: Do you have something to add to this discussion?  There is no mention of AppEngine by OP.  You're guessing but telling me to read closer.

Comment: 1st phrase = "I'm a noob and using Wordpress on Google cloud." Google cloud is a set of app's, including hosting over Python, PHP, also includes SQL data storage. ANY PHP app will be running into AppEngine or CloudCompute. Please be polite, and read more carefully. There's a lot of people watching GoogleCloud as free hosting when it is NOT really for that purposes. This is that i have to add to this discussion.

Answer (score 4):

In your Google development console dashboard, at the left, under Compute you have Instance of MV

1. click to see all your instance parameters
2. click on ssh button to access to your server
3. tape find / -name php.ini to find the directory of your php.ini
4. tape sudo nano in my case it was sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
5. find the line upload_max_filesize = 2M and change it to 20M or more
6. restart your server with sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

It worked fine for me !

Answer (score 2):

1. Install  Google Cloud SDK (GCS) https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/
2. GCS: Setup you account in Google Cloud SDK Shell   `gcloud auth login`
3. Get connection string from web console https://console.developers.google.com

   - YourProject > Compute > Compute Engine > VM instances
   - On instance line: connect/SSH > popup menu > view gcloud command
   - Copy gcloud compute command line
4. GCS: Run it in Google Cloud SDK Shell to open SSH  `gcloud compute --project "your_project-id" ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "wordpress-your_id"`
5. GCS: Copy php.ini to your localhost: `gcloud compute --project "your_project-id"  copy-files "wordpress-your_id":/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini  php.ini --zone "us-central1-a"`
6. Edit line `upload_max_filesize = 2M`  in php.ini located in your Cloud SDK folder
7. GCS: Upload back to the host in your home directory:`gcloud compute --project "your_project-id" php.ini copy-files "wordpress-your_id":~/php.ini  --zone "us-central1-a"`
8. SSH: Change user to root in PuTTY: `sudo /bin/bash`
9. SSH: Replace php.ini:  `cp php.ini /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
10. SSH: Restart service: `service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

I did this steps

1. In the terminal console you need to edit the correct php.ini, in my case was:

   vi /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
2. 2. I made the seek and changed the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size variables like this:

   post_max_size = 256M

   upload_max_filesize = 256M
3. I restarted the apache server

   /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

And work for me.

Answer (score -1):

You must know about how Google products works.

At least, there are two things you can control.

1. The memory that WP itself will try to use as max: `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');`
2. The value of the "container" you are using (600Mhz/128Mb on the free usage).

Even if it's running PHP, it's using their own infraestructure, based on Python and using it's own config files. So no .htaccess or php.ini will be parsed here. Just the config files that you can read about on the Documentation.

Anyway, im watching people's reports and being know that you can at least run the 128Mb of the minumun instance. Also, i don't recommend you to use AppEngine to host a blog.

Comment: WP for obvious reason has no right to overwrite PHP limits. Whatever you set in `wp-config.php ` for a limit, it will be _less or equal_ than the value set in `php.ini`. Plus,  the memory limit has nothing to do with `upload_max_filesize`. Downvoted.

Comment: He as called itself a noob on the Google, so don't forgot all is not obviosly to all people.The same way memory_limit and Apache values from htaccess, HAS NOT a upload_max_filesize. I say him that must know how the google product works, because are no under the normal behavior. Also, define 256Mb on the WP settings will not affect the 128Mb limit by design on the container, assuming free use. If it's not the free use, memory is still allocate about "what are you paying for". Downvote is a right, do it!