# How do I fully deploy a WordPress instance on GCE using the google console without using Bitnami?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have previously made WP GCE instances using Bitnami. Recently, I came across directions to make A WordPress instance directly in the google console using the "click to deploy" feature. A Bitnami installation makes the WP index come right up and getting an SSH key is really straight forward as well. These two items seem to be more of a challenge without Bitnami....

I followed all these directions to deploy WordPress on GCE. http://www.wpexplorer.com/install-wordpress-google-cloud/

The IP address goes to the Apache2 Debian Default Page (http://23.236.57.107) instead of the WP index page. How do I remedy this?

Also, how do I obtain an ssh key so I can connect via codeanywhere or transmit? The instance detail page in the google console shows SSH Keys none. There is no link to add a key there.

Comment: I posted a bug report as directed by Google support: https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=250&thanks=250&ts=1445019114 A few days later they had the bug corrected. The  WP deployment was effortless when I tried again. I'm still not able to get an SFTP connection. I will post this issue as a new question.

Comment: I see there is a bug#24999950 attached to the issue you posted, that means that Google is working on the issue, but there is no ETA on this I think.

Answer (score 1):

Google "Click To Deploy" WordPress Launcher works a lot better than Bitnami (which brands there install and is weird). Also, Google CTD allows you to now delete the "admin" user after your installation is up, so this is sweet. SFTP is an issue with me.

One other thing is to change the upload limits for WordPress via the PHP.INI file: [Wordpress upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018512/wordpress-upload-file-size?rq=1)