# Removing the Apache server signature in a Wordpress/GKE installation

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have an installation of Wordpress running in Kubernetes cluster in google cloud. The wordpress.yaml starts with:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
```

And then I have an Ingress on top of that. I wish to remove the Apache server signature (which is visible when running curl -I http://www.mysite.something) , and if I knew where to find the httpd.conf file this would be easier.

I can ssh into the project by "gcloud compute --verbosity=debug --project "wordpress-xyzblabla" ssh blabla"

And there I can mount disks, e.g. 
mount scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_gke-blabla /mnt/disks/foo

And when the disk is mounted at /mnt/disks/foo I find the entire wordpress directory structure containing the .htaccess and wp-content, and what not.

But I cannot find the the httpd.conf or apache.conf files/directories. How do I find/mount those directories, or is there another way to accomplish the removal of the Apache server signature?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this will help you:

[Locate and edit a WordPress .htaccess file in Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603298/locate-and-edit-a-wordpress-htaccess-file-in-google-compute-engine)

[Wordpress upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018512/wordpress-upload-file-size)

https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-disable-server-signature-by-editing-apache-htaccess-file/

Comment: Thanks for your links, but unfortunately these links do not provide any help for kubernetes clusters in google (kubernetes engine, gke), or where to find the appropriate (GKE) httpd.conf file where I can edit the ServerSignature.